# How to query hierarchy paths without the root node (as list of paths)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to get JSON-tree of the hierarchy (or some hierarchies, if there is different roots for this pattern - as `ps` in my example is list of paths) that I could achieve by:

```
MATCH p=(parent)-[:metaClassOf*]->(child)
WHERE NOT (parent)<-[:metaClassOf]-()
WITH COLLECT(p) AS ps
CALL apoc.convert.toTree(ps) yield value
RETURN value;
```

If I need to query only part of the hierarchy, I could specify the desired leaf to act as a root in my query:

```
MATCH (root {name: "The Root Name"})
MATCH p=(root)-[:metaClassOf*]->(child)
WHERE NOT (root)<-[:metaClassOf]-()
WITH COLLECT(p) AS ps
CALL apoc.convert.toTree(ps) yield value
RETURN value;
```

But how do I exclude the `root` node itself from the last query, as I don't want it to be in final JSON-tree? I will repeat, I need the list of paths that are coming from the root node, but without this root node and then convert them to JSON-tree.

I can't achieve that by filtering nodes after `UNWIND` the paths, as I don't know how to combine them back to list of paths to be able to use `apoc.convert.toTree(ps)` then:

```
MATCH (root {name: "The Root Name"})
MATCH p=(root)-[:metaClassOf*]->(C_Child)
WHERE NOT (root)<-[:metaClassOf]-()
UNWIND nodes(p) as ns
WITH ns as nss
WHERE NOT nss.name= The Root Name"
return nss
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query returns every tree (without the root node) of every `root` whose `name` is "The Root Name".

```
MATCH (root {name: "The Root Name"})-[:metaClassOf]->(n)
WHERE NOT ()-[:metaClassOf]->(root)
MATCH p=(n)-[:metaClassOf*0..]->()
WITH root, COLLECT(p) AS ps
CALL apoc.convert.toTree(ps) YIELD value AS tree
RETURN root, tree
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works wonderful! Ofc, I should had find sub-roots first then find paths from them.